# Order by substring of ID as integer in HQL with Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hql

Is there a way to order by substring of ID casted to integer using HQL or/and Criteria?

For example:

```
class Foo {
  String id
  String name
}
```

Sorted Dataset would look like:

```
90-1  David
90-4  Mike
101-1 Jack
101-2 Peter
105-1 Jon
105-7 Jane
```

With MySQL database and native sql it would be done like:

```
order by 
CAST(substring_index(id, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
CAST(substring(id, length(substring_index(id, '-', 1)) + 2) AS UNSIGNED)
```

I tried using formula as suggested but that did not work because UNSIGNED was treated as alias and generated SQL had _this.UNSIGNED

```
Integer fooFirstID
Integer fooSecondID

static mapping = {
    fooFirstID formula: "CAST(substring_index(id, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED)"
    fooSecondID formula: "CAST(substring(id, length(substring_index(id, '-', 1))
                           + 2) AS UNSIGNED)" 
}
```

I see that Hibernate supports substring as well as cast to Hibernate type but cannot find equivalent of a substring_index.

Thanks.

Comment: i'm not sure but it may be possible that this cast(thing as type) proprietary (i guess) feature of mysql is not supported by the hibernates' mysql dialect. Try to contact the mailing list to see if it's a bug or a missing feature.

Comment: It is supported from what I read here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions

Comment: Is a distinction between signed & unsigned truly important in this case?  If not, perhaps try: `CAST(substring_index(id, '-', 1) AS integer)`

Comment: Nope, not important, but same result this_.integer

Comment: Seems like Hibernate has trouble with the AS keyword in formulas (I see a few JIRA issues out there).  As a hacky workaround, you might try an implicit type conversion. Something like: `1 * substring_index(id, '-', 1)`

Comment: How big is the data set?  It may be more efficient to sort it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Formula annotation and order on the annotated property, it works fine.

```
@Formula("CAST(substring_index(id, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED)")
public varType getToto() {
  return toto;
}

@Formula("CAST(substring(id, length(substring_index(id, '-', 1)) + 2) AS UNSIGNED)")
public varType getTata() {
  return tata;
}
```

And then you do in HQL: order by toto,tata

Btw you could consider using a composite id.

Comment: Not working right now due to UNSIGNED not being recognized as type and treated as an alias so sql looks like: as this_.UNSIGNED not sure yet if its Hibernate or GORM adding that in grails

Comment: Sorry i don't know enough mysql UNSIGNED to give you the right answer, but at least you could try to remove the UNSIGNED and try to order on sting values to check my solution works. Strings can also be ordered, "1" < "2" < "3".

Comment: Sorting by String works but I can accomplish the same without using formula. The problem with sorting by string is that "1" < "10" < "2"

Comment: sorry i should have think about it :) have you tried something like using  @Formula("CAST(substring(id, length(substring_index(id, '-', 1)) + 2) AS UNSIGNED) AS myVar") ?

Comment: Thank you for trying :) both UNSIGNED and myVar now treated as alias and get this_. prefix

Comment: What about replacing by CONVERT(expr,UNSIGNED) ?

Comment: Nope, get the same this_.UNSIGNED

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the type does not get recognized as an Hibernate type. 'As' is treated as the alias binder no matter what you do.
This is strange, because as the Hibernate documentation states :

> cast(... as ...), where the second argument is the name of a Hibernate type, and extract(... from ...) if ANSI cast() and extract() is supported by the underlying database

Even though you are using mysql, you can try the postgre cast syntax :

```
substring_index(id, '-', 1)::integer
```

If you are using H2, it's INT, not INTEGER

```
cast(substring_index(id, '-', 1) as INT)
```

Also note that the relevant operations where you could use the unsigned notion in Java are binary, hex or octal conversions (for the leading bit, obviously). These always treat the Integer as an unsigned int anyway, so it does not matter.
If you really want to apply that notion, you'll have to use a short with a leading bit, and cast it to int, that will give you a 'truely unsigned' int.

Comment: Oh and make sure you are using the right Dialect too, as stated previously, the cast only work if it is supported by the underlying database.

Comment: Nope, MySQL does not like ::integer

Comment: It's a postgre syntax that gets recognized by Hibernate as a cast operation. I read that it's independant from the underlying implementation.